# Change location of capistrano.log file

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

My Capistrano 3 deploy writes a log to `/log/capistrano.log` but I'd like to change it. I've searched the official documentation but could not find anything.

I prefer to keep my deploy files separate to my application stuff so I have tidied them into their own `/cap` folder using:

```
# Capfile.rb
set :deploy_config_path, 'cap/deploy.rb'
set :stage_config_path, 'cap/deploy'
```

It would be great if my log in there too! How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Airbrussh formatter (default since Capistrano 3.5), you can set the log location like so:

```
set :format_options, log_file: 'cap/log/capistrano.log'
```

Documentation is here: https://github.com/mattbrictson/airbrussh#configuration

Comment: Ah yes! I forgot about the whole airbussh layer. Thanks. PS. "Airbrussh" definitely goes in my Top 10 Punny Tech Names along with Chef's "Berkshelf".